# how to register services to DI programally?

Tags: magento2

I know we can register service via di.xml, but how can we register services programally? I have lots of similar services, I'd like to register them via code instead of static xml file.

## Example

```
{
    "state1" : {
        "type" : "state_machine",
        "marking_store" : {
            "type" : "method",
            "property" : "state1"
        },
        "supports" : [ "Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order" ],
        "initial_marking" : "order_placed",
        "places" : [
            "order_placed",
            "processing",
        ],
        "transitions" : {
            "purchagePlate": {
                "from" : "order_placed",
                "to" : "processing"
            }
        }
    },
    "state2" : {
        "type" : "state_machine",
        "marking_store" : {
            "type" : "method",
            "property" : "state2"
        },
        "supports" : ["Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order"],
        "initial_marking" : "pending",
        "places" : [
            "pending",
            "requested",
        ],
        "transitions" : {
            "request_document": {
                "from" : ["pending"],
                "to" : "requested"
            }
        }
    },
    "state3" : {
        "type" : "state_machine",
        "marking_store" : {
            "type" : "method",
            "property" : "state3"
        },
        "supports" : ["Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order"],
        "initial_marking" : "pending",
        "places" : [
            "pending",
            "received",
            "dispatched"
        ],
        "transitions" : {
            "receive": {
                "from" : ["pending"],
                "to" : "received"
            },
            "dispatch": {
                "from" : ["received"],
                "to" : "dispatched"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Symfonfy workflow with Mangento2, Let's assume we have 3 workflow as the example above, then we will have 3 instances of workflow. Symfony workflow is too complex to configure manually, So I'd like to configure workflow programally.

Comment: can you give a short example?

Comment: I can't find any example.usually, we register services via di.xml, right? I'd like to register my services via code.

Comment: I was talking about an example for your services....How do you do it via di.xml for 1 or 2 services. and how would you like it to work.

Comment: If you come from the symfony world, where you need to register services, I may understand what you mean. I also think you don't need what you think you need. Any existing class can be used as a service in Magento. You don't need to declare it anywhere. di.xml is for configuring class dependencies, plugins and a few other things. That's why I asked for an example. It whoud make it easier to understand what you need.

Comment: @Marius, I updated the post, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with symfony workflows. I'll try to read up about it and get back to you if I find something.